# Are Module-Component structure and lazy loading the same in Angular Nativescript project in comparison to Angular projects?

Tags: angular, nativescript, native, angular-nativescript

So, I want to structure this project i am working with Angular and Nativescript. The probelem is i cant find any guide for a base flexible and robust architecture. Is it fine to follow the one that angular provides?

Comment: Angular is reused in NativeScript, except for some special cases like renderers, page router outlet etc., So, Yes you can follow what Angular gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add route url for all pages inside the project in app routing page like:-

**1. app.routing.module.ts:-**

```
 import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
 import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
 import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule" },
  { path: "login", loadChildren: "~/app/login/login.module#LoginModule" },
 ];

 @NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**2. home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{


 constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router) {

 }

 ngOnInit(): void {

 }

 login() {
    this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, also are dynamic imports fine with nativescript?

Comment: Something like this:
`{
    path: '',
    component: BlankLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'onboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/onboard/onboard.module').then(m => m.OnboardModule)
      },
    ]
  },`

Comment: Yes for dynaimc imports you use route param like { path: "home/:pagename", loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule" },

Comment: By dynamic import i mean, lazy loading import for modules.

`() => import('./views/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)`